# Can't upload a new version of app

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to upload version 2.0.1 of my app, it contains small bugfixes. I uploaded version 2.0 sep 25th. so not that long ago.

I have been getting the following errors on the attached pictures for a week, and i can not find a solution. Tryed several fixes, also tryed changing the new version to v2.1 but it did not help...

My app is only for iOS7, info.plist says version 2.0.1 both in bundle version and short version.

Any suggestions? Ask for needing information.

[image: Screens]

Comment: Most obvious possible problems: do you have multiple Info.plist files and are you sure this target uses the right one? Did you clean project, delete derived data etc.?

Comment: i am pretty sure i only have one info.plist file yes, and cleaning doesnt help either

Comment: Did you delete derived data? (quit Xcode and delete everything in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData). Also, try to copy the project into different folder and try again. Xcode's caching is sometimes really stubborn.

Comment: Did not help either /:

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled xcode and deleted all data, ran "Archive" and now found a mistake in the integration of Flurry, so i removed all code to Flurry and the files, and just added it again from new download. Works now

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I solve it with making the

> Bundle version string, short = 2.0.2

don't worry the app version will be 2.0.1

Try it.

Comment: Didnt help solving the problem